# Accessing ASP.NET membership stored procedures from classic ASP page

Tags: asp-classic, asp.net-membership

I have a classic asp site that requires login functionality.  There is an ASP.NET administrative site where logins will get set up.  I'm thinking about using ASP.NET Membership to manage/store the login information, and on my ASP site access the data through the Stored Procedures.  Am I asking for trouble here?  Has anybody successfully done this, or can anybody nip this idea in the bud before I get started?  Thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ASP.NET membership provider already builds the Stored procedures for you.  If you can access the DB where the membership is setup, you can directly access those stored procedures.

EDIT:  Found the articles I used when I did this.

[This is how you do it natively using a COM+ 'Hack'.](http://forums.asp.net/p/1197121/2080025.aspx#2080025) Taken from the ASP.NET forums.  It leads [here.](http://www.wwwcoder.com/Directory/tabid/68/type/art/site/4922/parentid/258/Default.aspx)

[This is how Scott Guthrie suggests it.](http://www.wwwcoder.com/Directory/tabid/68/type/art/site/4922/parentid/258/Default.aspx)  (Between ASP.NET 1.1 and 2.0+, but it's the same overall idea of sharing a single cookie.)

Comment: Yes, that was the question I was asking.  In theory it should work.  I was hoping to get some input from somebody who has actually done this.  I've only use ASP.NET Memberships twice before so I'm not 100% of any possible disadvantages of doing this.

Comment: I have done this.  The only disadvantage/difficulty would be allowing the ASP site to share the encrypted key with the ASP.NET site so your users didn't have to re-login.

The ASP.NET membership back-end generates a unique application-specific hash key it encodes into the authCookie that is setup when a user logs in.  The only difficulty would be replicating this, and even that is not impossible.  I'll find the article I followed when I did it.

That being said, there is an Authenticate stored procedure in the pre-defined SPs available for use.  It returns a boolean.